# Data synchronization issue when use connection pool on tomcat server

Tags: database, tomcat, servlets

I am developing a Servlet applicaiton.  It obtains a database connection from the connection pool supported by the Tomcat container to query and update database data.

I run into a problem.  The Servlet gets a database connection and then add a new table row or delete a table row.  After that, it commits the change.  Later, a connection is obtained to execute queries.  I find that the data returned from the queries using the second connection do not reflect the change made with the first database connection.

Isn't it strange?  The changes made with the first database connection have been committed successfully.  Why the new rows inserted do not appear in the later query?  Why the rows deleted still appear in the later query?

Does it relate to the setting of transaction level?

Can anyone help?

> 03-12: More Information (#1):

1. I use MySQL Community Server 5.6.
2. My servlet runs on Tomcat 7.0.41.0.
3. The Resource element in the conf/server.xml is as follows:

> ```
> <Resource type="javax.sql.DataSource"
>        name="jdbc/storewscloud"
>        factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
>        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
>        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myappdb"
>    maxActive="100"
>         minIdle="10"
>         maxWait="10000"
>         initialSize="10"
>         removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
>        removeAbandoned="true"
>        logAbandoned="true"
>        username="root"
>        password="xxxxxxxxxx"
> /></li>
> ```
>
> I do not use any cache explicitly.
>
> Every time the servlet gets a database connection, it turns the auto-commit mode of the connection off.
>
> When the servlet is invoked, a database connection is obtained.  The servet uses it to update data in the database.  After that, it commits the changes.  Then, it uses Apache HttpClients to invoke the same servlet to do some other thing which also obtains a database connection and execute query.  The later query returns 'old' data.  If I refresh the web page, the latest data are shown.  It looks like some party, mysql jdbc driver or connection object, cache the data somewhere.  I have no clue.
>
> 03-12: More Information (#2):
>   I did an experiment getting a connection without using the connection pool.  The result is correct.  So, the problem is caused by the connection pool.

To make the query return right data using the 2nd connection from the pool, I need to not only commit the data changes using the 1st connection from the pool but also CLOSE the 1st connection.

It seems that the data changes made are not completely saved in the database even the commit() is called until the close() is called.

Why?

Comment: Do the updated records exist if you query the database directly? Is there any caching going on? Are you sure your commit is working?

Comment: Which connection pool are you using (Tomcat has 2)? What is your database? What is your transaction isolation level? Are you using autocommit? No errors are occurring?

Comment: I updated my question as shown above today.  Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 1):

I found that there is a new version of C3P0 connection pool released recently.  I gave it a try.  It works!  The problems I had do not occur.  Therefore, I use it to replace the bundled connection pool of the Tomcat server.  For those who encounter the same problem as I do, C3P0 maybe a solution for you too.

[C3P0 Project URL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/?source=navbar)